# How to write unit test case for submitting form with drop-down box list in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, karma-jasmine

Hi I am writing uni test for submitting form which contains two drop-down box lists with submit button. This form is modal. When clicking on one button I am opening modal and populating drop-down with values. After user selects some value user can submit the form. I am writing unit test case for this functionality. Below is my form.

```
 <form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="permissionEditorForm" #f="ngForm" novalidate
                              (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && isPermissionValid(selectedUserRole.value,selectedScopeName.value) ? savePermission(selectedUserRole.value,selectedScopeName.value) : showErrorAlert('Please enter mandatory fields')">

                            <div>
                                <label>User Role</label>
                                <div ng-class="{'valid':userrole.$valid}">
                                    <select #selectedUserRole  id="userrole" autofocus name='userrole' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='userrole' required>
                                        <option value="">--Select User Role--</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let userrole of userroles; let i = index" [value]="userrole.userroleid" >
                                            {{userrole.username}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span *ngIf="(f.submitted && !userrole.valid && !userrole) || (!userrole.valid && userrole.dirty)" class="errorMessage">
                                        <i class="abb_icon_16 ui_error_circle1 erroricon"></i>  User Role Required!
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Scope Name</label>
                                <div>

                                    <select #selectedScopeName  autofocus name='scopename' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='scopename' required>
                                        <option value="">--Select Scope Name--</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let scope of scopes; let i=index" [value]="scope.scopeid" >
                                            {{scope.scopevalue}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span *ngIf="(f.submitted && !scopename.valid && !scopename) || (!scopename.valid && scopename.dirty)" class="errorMessage">
                                        <i class="abb_icon_16 ui_error_circle1 erroricon"></i>   Scope Name Required!
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" (click)="permissionmapModal.hide()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <button type="submit" id="savePermission" class="btn btn-primary">Add Permisson</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </form>
```

Below is the function called when the form is submitted.

```
 savePermission(userrolevalue, scopevalue) {

  }
```

I am trying to write unit test case for select some values in drop-down box list and submit. Below is my unit test case.

```
 it('add permission', () => {
   component.permissionform.form.controls.scopename.setValue('/bmw/v1/s1');
   component.permissionform.form.controls.userrole.setValue('subscriber');
   let savePermissionButton = 
   fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#savePermission');
   component.permissionform.form.valid;
   savePermissionButton.click();
 }
```

When the above test runs, method savePermission will be called but parameters will be empty. May I know my Is values are not set to my drop-down box list? If values were set then it userrolevalue, scopevalue should get some values. Can someone correct me to make the above code works? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing the click, directly test the function. Your job is to test **your code**, not to test if *Angular works correctly when you click on items*.

This would give something like this

```js
it('should submit the form', () => {
  const roleMock = {}; // Mock your value here
  const scopeMock = {}; // Same thing

  component.savePermission(roleMock, scopeMock);

  // Here you make your expects
});
```

If you don't know how to test or what to test, please give the code of your submit function so that I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much. Once I get values role and mock in my component then i know how to test. I mean to call my service which saves etc. But my question is, Is this is the right way to do it?

Comment: I've been learning unit testing for two years now. For the first year, I've been told that I had to test like you did. On the second year, a senior developer told me that unit testing is made to test if your code works as exepected, and if there is no side effect when you change something. He also said that unit tests should focus on the feature you're testing, and that you should mock dependencies. And when I asked him how to pass data to functions, he told me to mock them too. This makes a lot of sense to me, because it seems logical this way.

Comment: (In short, **I think this is the best practice**)

Comment: okay thanks. For me one of senior developer told that we should test end to end unit test that is from html to component. Unit test should cover end to end flow. Anyway this way I follow now. Thank you so much again

Comment: Well if it is the case, what would be the purpose of making e2e tests with protractor ? I made the same comment to my senior dev, and that's the answer I got : unit tests should test your code, e2e tests should test the user's behavior and the validity of the data.